# import user profiles in MOSS 2007 server into my SharePoint 2010

Tags: import, sharepoint-2010, user-profile

I want to import user profiles in MOSS 2007 server into my SharePoint 2010 server.

Can anyone please suggest how can i go about achieving the same.

Can we import user profiles using Business Data Connection in Configure Synchronization Connection in User Profile Service Application in SharePoint 2010.

Why i am doing this:

I want to crawl MOSS 2007 User Profile Database in SharePoint 2010.

Please Advice!!!

Thanks

Ketan Gandhi

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft Technet has good guidance for this upgrade aspect. I believe you want to follow the steps in the upgrade guide to [Upgrade the Shared Services Database](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263299.aspx#SSP).

There are quite a few steps, but this powershell script is a key to upgrading the user profiles from the SharePoint 2007 SSP Database to the SharePoint 2010 User Profile Service database:

```
New-SPProfileServiceApplication -applicationpool <ApplicationPoolName> -Name <ServiceApplicationName> -Profiledbname <DatabaseName> [-Profiledbserver <ServerName>]
```

Also, in the future, you might want to check out http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com where a lot of questions like these are answered more quickly.